# NVidia won't work for Lenovo T540p, Debian Jessie

Tags: lenovo-laptop, debian-jessie, nvidia-graphics-card

Got a brand new **Lenovo T540p** laptop to run **Debian Jessie**. It boots, but whatever I try the NVidia graphics won't kick in. I've done the NVidia installation many times for Debian. Also for Jessie. And yet in this case it won't work.

What I did:

1. Add 'non-free' and 'contrib' to the sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.
2. Run 'apt-get update'.
3. Run 'apt-get install nvidia-driver nvidia-xconfig'. The usual messages came about blacklisting Nouveau, etc... The installation was as expected.
4. Run 'nvidia-xconfig' to create '/etc/X11/xorg.config'
5. Reboot.

The usual Grub menu is shown - which draws very slowly - and surely it boots a Debian. The only unusual is the size of the characters of the scrolling text; they're really tiny. And finally the screen goes black with a flashing cursor. And there it stays.

X logging suggests the device could not be found. Hence no screen could be found either. However, everything seems to be in order. The device is there and 'nvidia-detect' confirms its presence and compatibility. And the packages are installed.

This smells like a device-specific problem. There is the potentially problematic "OS Optimization" feature in UEFI. It is disabled. I've tried anything I could think of. But I'm afraid I have to admit this problem is beyond my abilities. :-)

Anybody has an idea what else can I try ?

**uname -a**

```
Linux <host> 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1 (2014-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia**

```
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                0.5.1                                  amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libegl1-nvidia:amd64                  340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL libraries
ii  libgl1-nvidia-glx:amd64               340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL libraries
ii  libgles1-nvidia:amd64                 340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 1.x libraries
ii  libgles2-nvidia:amd64                 340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL|ES 2.x libraries
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:amd64               340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-ml1:amd64                   340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) runtime library
ii  nvidia-alternative                    340.65-2                               amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-detect                         340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA GPU detection utility
ii  nvidia-driver                         340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA metapackage
ii  nvidia-driver-bin                     340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup              20141201+1                             amd64        cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                  20141201+1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms                    340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-modprobe                       340.46-1                               amd64        utility to load NVIDIA kernel modules and create device nodes
ii  nvidia-settings                       340.46-2                               amd64        tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-support                        20141201+1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary graphics driver support files
ii  nvidia-vdpau-driver:amd64             340.65-2                               amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix - NVIDIA driver
ii  nvidia-xconfig                        340.46-1                               amd64        X configuration tool for non-free NVIDIA drivers
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia             340.65-2                               amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

**nvidia-detect**

```
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] [10de:1290] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

**dmesg**

```
[    2.270114] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    2.280419] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.619752] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    3.619759] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:50:34 PST 2014
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.46  (buildd@brahms)  Tue Oct  7 08:00:32 UTC 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**/var/log/Xorg.0.log**

```
[     3.575] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.2.901 (1.16.3 RC 1)
Release Date: 2014-12-09
[     3.575] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     3.575] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     3.575] Current Operating System: Linux no-nb-jgo-2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt2-1 (2014-12-08) x86_64
[     3.575] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=8aa62235-5297-46a0-a403-18ff956f1a7d ro quiet
[     3.575] Build Date: 09 December 2014  10:15:28PM
[     3.575] xorg-server 2:1.16.2.901-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[     3.575] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[     3.575]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     3.575] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     3.575] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Feb  6 10:14:13 2015
[     3.575] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     3.575] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     3.576] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[     3.576] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     3.576] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     3.577] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[     3.577] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     3.577] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     3.577] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     3.577] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     3.577] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     3.578] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     3.578]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     3.580] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     3.580] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     3.580] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     3.580] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     3.580] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     3.580] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f52cdebfd80
[     3.580] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     3.580]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     3.580]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[     3.580]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     3.580]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     3.580] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     3.593] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:221e rev 6, Mem @ 0xf1000000/4194304, 0xe0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[     3.594] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1290:17aa:221e rev 161, Mem @ 0xf0000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128
[     3.594] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     3.596] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[     3.667] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     3.667]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     3.667]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     3.668] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:10:06 PST 2014
[     3.668] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     3.669] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[     3.674] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     3.674]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     3.674]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     3.674] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  340.65  Tue Dec  2 08:47:36 PST 2014
[     3.674] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     3.675] (++) using VT number 7

[     3.687] (EE) No devices detected.
[     3.687] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     3.687] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[     3.687] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     3.687] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     3.687] (EE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `BusID "PCI:1:0:0"` to the Device section.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

**/var/log/Xorg.0.log**

```
    [     3.687] (EE) No devices detected.
    [     3.687] (EE) 
    Fatal server error:
    [     3.687] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
    [     3.687] (EE)
```

*Oh, there's no video card specified in xorg. Alright then. Let's take a look at the particulars we'll need to add one.*

**lspci**

```
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1)
```

*lspci tells you where on the PCI Bus the NVIDIA card is. Looks like we are at 1:00.0*

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
    ...
    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device0"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "Device0"
        Monitor        "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

*Well, for whatever reason, the Device section needs the address of the device on the PCI bus because autodetection for setup and running aren't cutting the mustard. Because Device is misconfigured-- specifying it in the Screen section also causes it to fail downstream from the actual problem.*

Nice job, BTW. Providing what was needed to answer the question.

I am typing on a T540p at this moment, and I am running the Nouveau driver, if that helps.